# Libgdx 3d Rotation another point

Tags: java, 3d, rotation, libgdx, bullet

I have a problem rotating my 3D object which is constructed of several boxes.
Here is a fragment of code for one box:

```
mb.part("scianka", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, Usage.Position | Usage.Normal,new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.RED))).box(2f,2f,2f);
```

Each box rotates about its center, but I need all the boxes to rotate "together"... This picture may explain it better..

[image]

I have only one idea to change origins Boxes on common

Comment: It would be better if you include the code for rotation as well in the question.

Comment: Are you rotating each part of the mesh?

Comment: did you find a solution?